# Get all the data from all the sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I get the data from all sheets?
For example, I have 5 sheets that need to be copy and 1 sheet as the main file.
Using that Main file I need to copy the data from sheet 1 to sheet 5. When all the data from sheet 1 is copied it will copy next the data from sheet 2 and so on and paste to the main sheet.
How can I achieve this using a formula?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain the bigger picture? You describe a terrible data architecture. Maybe if this was planned better from the outset, you wouldn't have to do any copying at all.

Comment: I would use the integrated feature [Get & Transform](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-Transform-in-Excel-2016-881c63c6-37c5-4ca2-b616-59e18d75b4de) to collect data from different source / sheets of a file. There are plenty tutorial on this topic, [e.g.](https://trumpexcel.com/combine-multiple-worksheets/)

Answer (score 0):

you could do this with VBA with following code

```
Private Sub CommandButton_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim xTCount As Variant
Dim xWs As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
LInput:
xTCount = Application.InputBox("The number of title rows", "", "1")
If TypeName(xTCount) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
If Not IsNumeric(xTCount) Then
    MsgBox "Only can enter number", , "Excel"
    GoTo LInput
End If
Set xWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Sheets(1))
xWs.Name = "Combined"
Worksheets("mod").Range("A1").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=xWs.Range("A1")
For i = 6 To Worksheets.Count
    Worksheets(i).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(CInt(xTCount), 0).Copy _
            Destination:=xWs.Cells(xWs.UsedRange.Cells(xWs.UsedRange.Count).Row + 1, 1)
Next
xWs.Columns("A:ZZ").AutoFit
End Sub
```